# google search clone error

Tags: java, php, google-search

I am currently using greekdevs google clone script but for some reason all their versions have the same error only the the web search if you type more than one word it doesn't bring up and results, I enabled PHP errors and it brings up "Notice: Undefined variable: results in" I've been through the code again and again but I am not experienced enough to fix this problem and since they are no longer updating this project I am hoping someone on here can help me fix this please.

This is the link to the project: http://greekdev.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/google-clone-script.html

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If they have stopped support, then it probably means something wasn't right. Recommend moving to something different.

As for your error, `Notice: Undefined variable: results in`, the error can be found from this output. It will let you know the line, and the file in which `results` isn't being defined. In this case you need to make sure that the variable [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

`if(isset($results)){}`

or

`if(isset($ARRAY['results'])){}`

Comment: It works perfectly with one word, which file would this be inserted into thankyou for the help

Answer (score 0):

This bug is fixed in version 1.2. Check it out: http://sourceforge.net/projects/googleclone

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider add a reference (or a quote) to the change log so people can easily verify your answer.